# Why did the Haskell typesystem fail to catch this?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, typechecking

The following compiles without warning or error.

```
factors n = [x | x<-[1..n], n `mod` x == 0]
perfects n = [x | x <- [1..n], x == sum (factors (init x))]
main = putStrLn "hello"
```

Even though I made a mistake in it.

```
perfects n = [x | x <- [1..n], x == sum (factors (init x))]  -- incorrect
perfects n = [x | x <- [1..n], x == sum (init (factors x))]  -- should have been
```

Where is the static type checking to rescue?

The reason I think it should have caught the mistake is:

- `factor` clearly expects an `Integral` since its argument is used with `mod`, while `init` returns a `List`
- not to mention that `x` is drawn from a `List` of `Integers` and `init` expects a `List`

Comment: The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the type ghc has deduced for it you can see

```
perfects :: forall a. (Eq a, Integral [a]) => [a] -> [[a]]
```

So if you have an instance that makes lists be in class `Integral` it works.
And ghc doesn't know that's not what you intend.

You'll get an error if you put the intended type signature on `perfects`, or of you use `perfects` in the way you intended (change `main` to `print (perfects 42)`).

**EDIT** This makes your code do something (nonsensical):

```
module Main where
factors n = [x | x<-[1..n], n `mod` x == 0]
perfects n = [x | x <- [1..n], x == sum (factors (init x))]

instance Num [a]
instance Integral a => Integral [a]
instance Real a => Real [a]
instance Enum [a] where
    enumFromTo _ _ = []

main = print (perfects 5)
```

So what you wrote could be what you intended.  This is why it's good to always write type signatures, so that the compiler can see what you had in mind.  Or at least, you should check that the inferred type is what you intended.

Comment: you are right in technical terms, but the function as it is written is just wrong, I still do not get why init is allowed to be called with an integer

Comment: @user3309706: That's because Haskell integer literals are overloaded, so `1` can be a list if there is a `Num` instance for lists, and similarly `[1..n]` could be a list of lists given the appropriate instances, so there's nothing preventing `x` from being a list.

Comment: ok, thanks, Is that considered a (mis)feature of Haskell? I clearly consider it a misfeature!

Comment: No it's not a misfeature for exactly the reasons augustss points out.  If you actually try to use `perfects` or if you put a correct  type signature on `perfects` then you will get a type error.

Comment: @user3309706 why augustss comment is valid, and it is not a misfeature. Did you try to compile `perfects 10`? That's when I got the type error "you haven't proven [a] is a Integral arising from a use of `perfects`", and no proof [a] is a Num arising from a use of `10`. Out of context though, i.e. out of application of perfects, i.e. when you have not a single use of it, it may well be valid code.

Comment: I would accept the answer if the first sentence would disappear. Because there *is* smth wrong with the function, namely that it does not produce correct results, even if it is correct from a typing point-of-view.

Comment: @user3309706 Agreed, from your point of view there is something wrong.  It's just not wrong enough that the typechecker can tell.

Comment: @user3309706: The only "wrongness" here is the discrepancy between the meaning of what you intended and what you wrote. The code you wrote is perfectly meaningful, which is why the compiler accepts it—it just doesn't mean what you expected. It's similar to, say, writing `x - y` in a context one should have written `x + y`; we don't normally expect compilers to catch that one, do we?

Answer (score 5):

What augustss said, but I'll add some thoughts.

The issue (not problem!) here is that Haskell makes a tradeoff: more flexibility, at the cost of concrete error reporting. Since Haskell just allows many more things, there are a lot of situations where, compared to more mainstream languages, it either can't report an error, or the error it reports is more abstract than such other languages would report.

For example, suppose you meant to type `1 + 2`, but you fat fingered and typed `1 0 2`.    Here's how Python responds:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 0 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 0 2
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Simple: "you typed something wrong."  Now Haskell:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> 1 0 2

<interactive>:2:1:
    No instance for (Num (a0 -> a1 -> t0)) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Num (a0 -> a1 -> t0))
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: 1 0 2
    In an equation for `it': it = 1 0 2

<interactive>:2:3:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `0'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the first argument of `1', namely `0'
    In the expression: 1 0 2
    In an equation for `it': it = 1 0 2

<interactive>:2:5:
    No instance for (Num a1) arising from the literal `2'
    The type variable `a1' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the second argument of `1', namely `2'
    In the expression: 1 0 2
    In an equation for `it': it = 1 0 2
```

In Python, `1 0 2` is a syntax error.  In Haskell, `1 0 2` means apply the function `1` to the arguments `0` and `2`.  Haskell's error message isn't "you can't do that," but rather, "you haven't told me how to coerce a number to a two-argument function" (no instance for `Num (a0 -> a1 -> t0)`).

In your case, you managed to write something that Haskell knows how to interpret, but means something very different from what you meant.  The best thing to do here, as a programmer, is to use top-level type declarations that describe your intent, and then the compiler can check against those.

---

Final note: keep in mind that you can do this in Haskell:

```
-- | Treat lists of numbers as numbers.  Example:
--
-- >>> [1..3] * [2..5]
-- [2,3,4,5,4,6,8,10,6,9,12,15]
--
instance Num a => Num [a] where
    xs + ys = [x + y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
    xs * ys = [x * y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
    xs - ys = [x - y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
    negate xs = map negate xs
    abs xs = map abs xs
    signum xs = map signum xs
    fromInteger x = [fromInteger x]



-- | Treat functions as numbers if they return numbers.  The functions
-- must have the same argument type.  Example:
--
-- >>> 1 0 2
-- 1
instance Num a => Num (r -> a) where
    f + g = \r -> f r + g r
    f * g = \r -> f r * g r
    f - g = \r -> f r - g r
    negate f = negate . f
    abs f = abs . f
    signum f = signum . f
    fromInteger x = const (fromInteger x)
```

Same thing can be done with the `Integral` class.